# PostgreSQL 9.3: Return strings from function

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following function called as `pro()`. From which I want to return the strings by union all of two `select` statements and product output.

**Function**: pro()

## My try:

```
create or replace function pro()
returns varchar as

$$

declare
    sql varchar;
    q varchar;
begin
    sql := 'SELECT DISTINCT  CAST(COUNT(ProductNumber) as varchar) ||'' - Count of the product Number '' as Descp
        FROM product
        UNION ALL
        SELECT DISTINCT CAST(COUNT(ProductName) AS varchar) || '' - Count of the product Name '' as Descp
        FROM product';

    raise info '%',sql;

    execute sql into q;

    return q;

end;
$$

language plpgsql;
```

**Calling Function**:

```
select pro();
```

This returning only the first part of select statement:

```
 ______________________________________
|pro                                   |
|character varying                     |
|______________________________________|
|6 - Count of the product Number       |
|______________________________________|
```

But the **expected** result should be:

```
 ______________________________________
|pro                                   |
|character varying                     |
|______________________________________|
|6 - Count of the product Number       |
|______________________________________|
|6 - Count of the product Name         |
|______________________________________|
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try use these functions :

**using `plpgsql`**

```
create or replace function pro1()returns 
table ( 
       descp text
      )
as
$$
begin
    return QUERY execute (
         'SELECT DISTINCT  CAST(COUNT(product) as varchar) ||'' - Count of the product Number '' as Descp
         FROM product
         UNION ALL
         SELECT DISTINCT CAST(COUNT(productid) AS varchar) || '' - Count of the product Name '' as Descp
         FROM product');
end;
$$
language plpgsql;
```

or

**using `sql`**

```
create or replace function pro2() returns table  ( descp text) 
as
$$
  SELECT DISTINCT  CAST(COUNT(product) as varchar) ||' - Count of the product Number ' as Descp
  FROM product
    UNION ALL
  SELECT DISTINCT CAST(COUNT(productid) AS varchar) || ' - Count of the product Name 'as Descp
  FROM product;
$$
language sql;
```

Comment: Panther, Yeah! Got it. Thank you so much.

Comment: `RETURN QUERY EXECUTE` is not necessary, a simple `RETURN QUERY` should be enough, if there are no dynamic query parts -- also note, that such simple result can also be declared as `RETURNS SETOF TEXT`, but of course with `RETURNS TABLE` a column alias can be specified at function declaration level.